# Table Filtering, Sorting, Distinct Records using jquery/javascript/css in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There will be 6 tabs in html page i.e A,B,C,D,E,F and 2 dropdowns.

Working Behavior is : User will select one value from 2 dropdowns. Then based on value selected, the filtering needs to be applied on html table present in each table. 
`

```
var options = $("#comboB").html();
$("#comboA").change(function(e) {
    var text = $("#comboA :selected").text();
    alert(text);
    $("#comboB").html(options);
    $('#comboB :not([value^="' + text + '"])').remove();

});
$("#comboB").change(function(e) {
    var text = $("#comboB :selected").text();
    alert(text);
    var allRows = $("tr");
    allRows.hide();
    $("tr:contains('" + text + "')").show();

});



<div class="dd">
<select id="comboA">
<option value="">Select Value</option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="D">D</option>
<option value="E">E</option>
<option value="F">F</option>    
</select>

<select id="comboB">
<option value="">Select Value</option>
<option value="A">A 1</option>
<option value="A">A 2</option>
<option value="A">A 3</option>
<option value="B">B 1</option>
<option value="B">B 2</option>
<option value="B">B 3</option>
<option value="B">B 4</option>
<option value="C">C 1</option>
<option value="D">D 1</option>
<option value="D">D 2</option>
<option value="E">E 1</option>
<option value="E">E 2</option>
<option value="E">E 3</option>
<option value="E">E 4</option>
<option value="F">F 1</option>
<option value="F">F 2</option>
<option value="F">F 3</option>
<option value="F">F 4</option>
<option value="F">F 5</option>
<option value="F">F 6</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="tbdata">
<table id="Fdata" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
        <th>F</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 2</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 2</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 1</td>
        <td class="F">F 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 1</td>
        <td class="F">F 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 1</td>
        <td class="F">F 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 1</td>
        <td class="F">F 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 1</td>
        <td class="F">F 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 1</td>
        <td class="F">F 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 2</td>
        <td class="F">F 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 2</td>
        <td class="F">F 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 2</td>
        <td class="F">F 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 2</td>
        <td class="F">F 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 2</td>
        <td class="F">F 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 2</td>
        <td class="F">F 6</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 3</td>
        <td class="F">F 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 3</td>
        <td class="F">F 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 3</td>
        <td class="F">F 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 3</td>
        <td class="F">F 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 3</td>
        <td class="F">F 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 3</td>
        <td class="F">F 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 4</td>
        <td class="F">F 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 4</td>
        <td class="F">F 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 4</td>
        <td class="F">F 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 4</td>
        <td class="F">F 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 2</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 4</td>
        <td class="F">F 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 4</td>
        <td class="F">F 6</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 1</td>
        <td class="F">F 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 1</td>
        <td class="F">F 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 2</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 1</td>
        <td class="F">F 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 1</td>
        <td class="F">F 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 1</td>
        <td class="F">F 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 1</td>
        <td class="F">F 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 2</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 1</td>
        <td class="F">F 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 2</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 1</td>
        <td class="F">F 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 2</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 1</td>
        <td class="F">F 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="A">A 1</td>
        <td class="B">B 1</td>
        <td class="C">C 1</td>
        <td class="D">D 1</td>
        <td class="E">E 1</td>
        <td class="F">F 4</td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>
```

[Link to code that I have tried so far](http://jsfiddle.net/anjsfiddle/BZNpH/5/).

Now I am not sure how to do following things.

**1)** Assume User has selected any value from dropdown, then i am able to filter html table. If user has selected F then only F columns should be visible. Also only the distinct values should be displayed (There are duplicate values )

**2)** If i select the first value from 2nd dropdown, then change event is not called due to which filtering is not happening. How to resolve this?

**3)** I have to create tabs for each Option(A,B,C..) and after selecting dropdown value, and if user goes to A tab, then A column should be displayed. If B tab is selected then B column should be displayed. It should display value based on value selected in dropdown.
I created one html page with navigation tabs, but not sure how to integrate that with this.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this ([**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/BZNpH/9/))

```
var options = $("#comboB").html();
    $("#comboA").change(function(e) {
    var text = $("#comboA :selected").text();
    $("#comboB").html(options);
    $('#comboB :not([value^="' + text + '"])').remove();
    $("#comboB").prepend($('<option/>', { 'html':'Select Value' }));
    $("table#Fdata tr").show().find('td').show();
});

$("#comboB").change(function(e) {
    if($(this).find('option:selected').text() == 'Select Value') return;
    var text = $("#comboB :selected").text();
    $("table#Fdata tr").show().find('td').show();
    $("table#Fdata tr").not("tr:contains('" + text + "')").hide();
    $("table#Fdata tr:visible > td").not("tr td:contains('" + text + "')").hide();
});
```

You are filtering (showing) `tr` so in a `tr` there may be some `td`'s that contains other than the selected text.

Comment: Thanks. Its working as expected. Few things 1) How to remove duplicates as after filtering it has duplicate values 2) How can i move this info into tabs i.e. There should be 6 tabs from A to F and when user clicks on A then A column should be displayed..Please suggest

Comment: @user2223335, Welcome, can't tell about tabs without a visible image, make a fiddle. Not sure about duplicates you are talking about, can you tell me in details ?

Comment: 1) Regarding Duplicate : Select A and Then A2 from second dropdown, it displays 2 records.I wanted it to display 1 record as both are same. Distinct record should be there.2) http://jsfiddle.net/anjsfiddle/BZNpH/11/ on this link, i have created the tabs. I have to combine both the scripts but not sure how to do

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot. Can you suggest how to integrate with tabs.For tabs, i created one fiddle jsfiddle.net/anjsfiddle/BZNpH/11